# pure query to sequelize

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

i would like someone to help me with this query to convert it on sequelize, i tried but without success.

```
SELECT id,name,startdate FROM ?? where DATE(startdate) = curdate() + interval 1 day order by ut desc;
```

My approach:

```
where: models.Sequelize.where(models.Sequelize.fn('DATE', models.Sequelize.col('startdate')), models.Sequelize.fn('curdate'), '+ interval 1 day'),
attributes: ['name', 'startdate']
```

Error that i face is here

```
Executing (default): SELECT `name`, `startdate` FROM `event` AS `event` WHERE DATE(`startdate`) [object Object] '+ interval 1 day';
```

if i try without this ,'+ interval 1 day' on this approach  models.Sequelize.where(models.Sequelize.fn('DATE', models.Sequelize.col('startdate')), models.Sequelize.fn('curdate')

it works but i need to add a interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `.fn` :

```
models.Sequelize.fn('curdate'), '+ interval 1 day')
```

to `.literal` :

```
models.sequelize.literal('curdate() + interval 1 day')
```